# How to upload a jacoco report dumped by the jvm to SonarQube?

Tags: java, sonarqube, code-coverage, jacoco

During my build pipeline, the integration tests invoke application endpoints, via network transport. After this step the application's JVM dumps a jacoco report into a local file. How can I upload this report file to SonarQube?

Comment: Have you tried the [documented properties](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Code+Coverage+by+Unit+Tests+for+Java+Project) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code coverage (similar to the measures) is always linked to an *analysis*.

So I suggest these steps:

1. generate your jacoco report file as usual
2. upload the file to the machine, where you Sonar analysis is done
3. run an analysis, by setting the `sonar.jacoco.reportPaths` property to the location of the uploaded file